# group the string elements with size two

Tags: python

```
myl = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I want to group the string elements with size two as shown below:

```
[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e']]
```

I tried as follows:

```
print [myl[i:i+2] for i in len(myl)]
```

What is wrong with?

Comment: The list comprehension will step through the string named `myl` a single character at a time.  You can't index a string by characters (you'd have to do something really ugly like: [myl[myl.index(i):myl.index(i)+1] ... and that would break at the end of the string, and be invalid for any strings with duplicate characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in len(myl)` doesn't make any sense. `len(myl)` is just a number, so you can't iterate through it.

You can use:

```
[myl[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(myl),2)]
```

Here `range(0,len(myl),2)` means "every other number in the given range", so `i` takes the values `0, 2, 4` and you get `myl[0:2]`, `myl[2:4]`, and `myl[4:6]`.

Comment: A user tried to add a comment as an edit: "Also in addition always remember that range function doesn't include the last element itself. For example if I say range(0,len(myl),2) then it wont consider till len(myl) but till len(myl)-"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
>>> myl = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> [myl[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range((len(myl) +1)/2)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]

>>> myl = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> [myl[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range((len(myl) +1)/2)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

>>> myl = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'f', 'g']
>>> [myl[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range((len(myl) +1)/2)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite what you want:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
myl = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print list(izip_longest(myl[::2], myl[1::2]))
```

result:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', None)]
```

Here is another solution:

```
myl = ['a','b','c','d','e']
l = zip(myl[::2], myl[1::2])
if not len(l)%2:
    l.append((myl[-1],))
print l
```

result:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e',)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an improved version of the function below:

```
#!python
def chunker(size, seq):
    return [seq[n-size:n] for n in range(size, len(seq)+size, size)]
```

The tricky part of this is in setting up the `range` arguments to start at "size" offset and step across the sequence in size steps.  It relies on the quirk of Python slices which allows any index larger than the end on the sequence (though some calls to `max()` would get around that if it were necessary).  When I've tried to write this with a range starting at zero and reversing the index (looking "forward" rather than backwards from the base index) I've found all sorts of boundary errors that this "backwards" version doesn't exhibit.  Probably I'm being stupid with that.

Here's the old, verbose version (but suitable for any iterable, even those which can't take slices):

```
#!python   
def chunker(stride, seq):
    '''Return a list of lists by breaking seq into chunks of length stride
    '''
    results = list()
    part = list()
    for each in seq:
        if len(part) == stride:
            results.append(part)
            part = list()
        part.append(each)
    if part:
        results.append(part)  # Keep any trailing partial chunk
        # but don't append an empty part if the seq ended on an even
        # stride
    return results
```

I realize this may seem awfully verbose.  But it is robust and will work with any iterable sequence and it is generalized for any positive integer as a stride.